# reactjs: An example for formik form with datatime picker using reactstrap ui

Tags: reactjs, formik, reactstrap

I am using `reactstrap` and `formik` for forms

I want to have a `datetime` picket in my form.

I am looking for an example for this. Whats is the best way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this one:
[React-DateTime-Picker](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-datetime-picker/)

Comment: will it work with formik

Comment: Formik is just a way to display the options, you can use whatever you like and connect it to the Formik, and this is a good website.
BTW, thank you for the upvote.